# How do you get to the guest filesystem from the host in VMWare Fusion?

Tags: windows-7, macos, vmware-fusion

I have a Mac host and a Windows guest.  I use the Mac terminal for development.  How do I access the guest's file system from the host terminal?  I am using VMWare Fusion.

How about from Finder?

I realize that I can share the entire hard drive of the Windows guest and then set a mount point in the Mac host.  Is there another way?

Comment: *> I realize that I can share the entire hard drive of the Windows guest and then set a mount point in the Mac host* – this is the way it's meant to be used. Any reason for wanting to do it differently? Any constraints?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an VMware-specific way to get at the guest's filesystem from the host while the guest is running. Shared folders works the other way, from inside the guest you can get to specifically shared folders from the host. When the guest is powered off, you can mount the vmdk files that make up the virtual disk as long as you have a filesystem driver for the filesystem the guest OS uses.

Solve your problem as if the Windows guest is another computer on the network.